# MultiChoiceMode with custom backgroundSelector

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an android listView with multiChoiceMode and contextual actionBar.

Recently I updated the background of my listItems (new card layout like google now ;) ) and that's why I needed a custom selector. All works fine but when I try to long press a listItem, contextual actionBar shows up but the selected listItem doesn't stay highlighted.

Here is my code of my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_card"/>
</selector>
```

and this is the code of my listView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
</ListView>
```

I have been trying all selection states of the list selector (including state_activated) but nothing worked.

Many thanks in advance
Gabriel Unterholzer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `state:activated` instead of `state:checked`.

See here: [ListFragment multi-choice does not show selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318113/listfragment-multi-choice-does-not-show-selection)